# Meaning of Double.doubleToLongBits(x)

Tags: java, eclipse, equals, hashcode

I am writing a class `Vec2D`, representing a 2 dimensional vector. I store `x` and `y` in `double`s.

When asked to generate `equals(Object obj` and `hashCode()`, eclipse generated this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    long temp;
    temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(x);
    result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(y);
    result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Vec2D other = (Vec2D) obj;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(x) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.x))
        return false;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(y) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.y))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

What is the significance of `Double.doubleToLongBits(x)` in this context? Can I not simply write `x != other.x`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short answer: Eclipse uses [Double.doubleToLongBits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits(double)) because that's what [Double.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) does:**

> The result is `true` if and only if the argument is not `null` and is a Double object that represents a `doubl`e that has the same value as the `double` represented by this object. For this purpose, two `double` values are considered to be the same if and only if the method [`doubleToLongBits(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits(double)) returns the identical `long` value when applied to each.

Long answer: the JLS specifies a few differences between Double.equals and ==. For one difference specified in [JLS 4.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) and [JLS 15.21.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1):

> Positive zero and negative zero compare equal; thus the result of the expression `0.0==-0.0` is `true` and the result of `0.0>-0.0` is `false`. But other operations can distinguish positive and negative zero; for example, `1.0/0.0` has the value positive infinity, while the value of `1.0/-0.0` is negative infinity.

Another regards `NaN`:

> If either operand is NaN, then the result of `==` is `false` but the result of `!=` is `true`.
>
> Indeed, the test `x!=x` is `true` if and only if the value of x is NaN.

As you can see, **it's possible for two double values to compare with `==` but actually correspond to different behavior when used in math and hash tables**. Thus, when writing a generated equality method, Eclipse makes the assumption that two doubles are only equal if and only if all operations that can be done to them are identical, or (equivalently) if they were autoboxed and compared with their `equals` methods. This is particularly important if switching between `double` and `Double`—it would be particularly unexpected for equality properties to differ there.

Of course, you're free to drift from that assumption: Regardless of whether it's a good idea, you may assign special cases to any of the many possible NaN representations, in which case `Double.doubleToRawLongBits()` would be a better match for your `equals` and `hashCode` methods. By the same token, your use case might treat objects with +0.0 and -0.0 as equivalent and guarantee that NaN values are not possible, in which case a raw `==` comparison may work better for `equals` (but at which point emulating the same criteria for `hashCode` becomes difficult).

Comment: `+0.0==-0.0` results true, can you please explain how? I read java docs, they have mentioned the same condition. But I am unable to understand how does the equality operator result in `true`. I mean how it is calculated internally?

Comment: @PrasannaSasne That's a very different question than this one; if you'd like more details, that's probably better asked with a top-level question that links to this question and answer. As a preview, though, Java bytecode specifies [floating-point compare operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings), and assembly languages like x86 [have floating point opcodes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/817-5477/eoizy.html), so my semi-educated guess is that "the Java virtual machine delegates it to the physical processor".

Answer (score 5):

Because `==` and `!=` follow IEEE-754 semantics for doubles, `Double.NaN != Double.NaN` and `0.0 == -0.0`. These behaviors may not be what you want, so `Double.doubleToLongBits()` converts the 64 bits of `double` data to 64 bits of `long` data so that operations like bit shifts and XOR work.

Honestly, though, I would say that the use of `doubleToLongBits` is a bug here, since if you care about exact equality you should be using [`Double.doubleToRawLongBits()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits%28double%29) (which does not perform any translations on the `double` data at all) instead.

Comment: actually inside doubleToLongBits, it call doubleToRawLongBits

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at the online javadoc yields this:

> Returns a representation of the specified floating-point value according to the IEEE 754 floating-point "double format" bit layout.
>
> ...
>
> In all cases, the result is a long integer that, when given to the longBitsToDouble(long) method, will produce a floating-point value the same as the argument to doubleToLongBits (except all NaN values are collapsed to a single "canonical" NaN value).

So it's probably a way of standardizing the `double` representations of `x` and `y`, as NaN can have multiple `double` representations